# Regex Pattern Matching to an array

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string defined as follows:

```
st = "The quick {{brown}} fox jumped over the {{fence}}."
```

To remove the {{ }}, I am doing the following:

```
st.gsub(/{{(.*?)}}/, '\1') 
=> "The quick brown fox jumped over the fence."
```

What I would like to do now is put each of the items that matched the regular expression into an array, so that the end result looks like:

```
arr = []
puts arr => ['brown', 'fence']
puts st => "The quick brown fox jumped over the fence."
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub), [`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) accepts optional block parameter. The return value of the block is used as a replacement string.

```
st = "The quick {{brown}} fox jumped over the {{fence}}."
arr = []
st.gsub!(/{{(.*?)}}/) { |m| arr << $1; $1 }
st
# => "The quick brown fox jumped over the fence."
arr
# => ["brown", "fence"]
```

Comment: Can't accept this answer for 10 minutes, but this is the answer and it works fine in my IRB. Will accept soon :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
st.gsub!(/{{(.*?)}}/).with_object([]){|_, a| a.push($1); $1} #=> ["brown", "fence"]
st #=> "The quick brown fox jumped over the fence."
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes. You are right. I first had it, and then somehow removed it. I was wrong.